# Vim "paste once" without update of undo

Tags: vim, scripting, text-editor, pasting

To implement pasting only once I can use:

```
noremap <silent> p p:let @"=""<cr>
```

This clears register after pasting, so that following paste will not work. What will however happen is empty pasting which updates undo. So pressing p `3` times will require `3` undo calls to undo the initial paste.

How to suppress this? I tried something like:

```
:noremap <expr> @" != "" ? p:let @"="" : <Nop> <cr>
```

But it doesn't impose any change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one is working for me:

```
:noremap <silent> <expr> p @" != "" ? 'p:let @"=""<cr>' : ""
```

To be a bit shorter:

```
:noremap <silent> <expr> p @" != "" ? 'pq"q' : ""
```

Comment: Strange, both are working for me; i often use `qXq` to empty any X reg, and it's working with the `@"` reg as well (I discovered this by answering your question)... nervertheless, it's not a problem if the 1st one works!

Comment: Checked that it indeed works when pasted into Vim, but not when put into my plugin and run that way